# elpa + ESS + auto-complete works only partially

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, ess, elpa

in an Emacs-loving rampage I installed a bunch of packages via elpa (MELPA/marmalade). [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSAuto-complete) I see that ESS supports advanced AC with a fancy dropdown menu, with documentation etc. out of the box. However I can only use the basic one (e.g. I write "library" once, enter, write "lib", complete).

Is there anything special I have to do? I am no LISP/.emacs genius so maybe I am missing something. I did try some manual flags (e.g. `(setq ess-use-auto-complete t)` as suggested somewhere) but no hope.

I'm using Emacs 24.3 on OSX (shouldn't make much difference) and a recent ESS (13.09); my .emacs merely `require`s ESS and AC (plus `(ac-config-default)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for suggestion, the page on emacswiki does indeed look good.
So I've just installed from elpa as you did. And I didn't get the completion
as you did. But then I did <kbd>C-c C-b</kbd> `ess-eval-buffer`, and the completion
and floating docs are there. And there you go.

Comment: HA I missed that. I am not sure why it doesn't do it on `M-x r-mode` or progressively or whatever (e.g. jedi on python-mode automatically checks imports etc.), but surely it can be configured. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to benefit from full completion you need to have at least one R process running. The same is valid for eldoc completion.